# VSCode Search - dismiss active result not focusing next result

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am wondering why seemingly all of a sudden VSCode is not exhibiting a behavior I am confident it once did.

That behavior would be that when I am searching using VSCode's built in search tool it does not change my focus to the next search result when I dismiss the current result. See video below where my cursor stays focused on the open file which is the dismissed result.[demonstration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IBJrP.gif).

I would expect that when I dismiss a search result if it is the currently selected one the focus jumps to the next result. Maybe this never was a feature but I am increasingly certain that it was. I am having trouble finding documentation around the dismiss feature but below I've linked what I've dug up so far. None of it seems to conclusively answer this for me one way or another.

- https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/48911
- https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/43976
- https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/48740

The third link specifically seems to be evidence to support my claim that this once was the functionality.

You can see the behavior in the gif below:

[image: example issue gif]

Notice on the right hand side how the line numbers are changing when they dismiss the active selection. This almost imperceptible clue shows the editor is changing focus to the now selected search result as I described.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would seem this issue is resolved in the [1.56.X](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_56) versions recently released. I booted up my editor a few days ago and was prompted to update to  [1.56.X](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_56) and as soon as I did the functionality of focusing to the next search result on dismissal of currently selected result returned.

In terms of where this issue was introduced/fixed I've no idea. I did a fair bit of reading through the relevant VSCode [releases on github](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/releases) but didn't see anything documenting the issue nor fixing it.

I had originally encountered the issue when my system updated from [1.52.X](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_52) to [1.53.X](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_53) and at the time I reproduced the issue on two different Windows machines. I observed the functionality working on [1.52.X](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_52) then performed the upgrade to [1.53.X](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_53) and the functionality broke/went away.

At this time I tried to reproduce the broken functionality using those versions and cannot. I suspect perhaps some sort of cache memory is involved making it not fall back to the broken state when I downgrade explicitly but given that I found a version that fixed it I won't pursue reproducing any further.